# What does it mean to "not get a callback at all" in Node.js error handling in TJ's farewell post?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently, I've been read the TJ's blog article: ["Farewell Node.js"](https://medium.com/code-adventures/4ba9e7f3e52b).

I'm not quite understand about the Node fails part. Here it is:

> Error-handling in Go is superior in my opinion. Node is great in the sense that you have to think about every error, and decide what to do. Node fails however because:
>
> - you may get duplicate callbacks
> - you may not get a callback at all (lost in limbo)
> - you may get out-of-band errors
> - emitters may get multiple “error” events
> - missing “error” events sends everything to hell
> - often unsure what requires “error” handlers
> - “error” handlers are very verbose
> - callbacks suck

What specific problem is being referred to when the author writes *"you may not get a callback at all (lost in limbo)"*?

Comment: @cookiemonster I know what is the limbo mean. I want to know why?~

Comment: +1. totally legitimate question. I had to think about it a bit and I don't think it's immediately clear from the post.

Comment: @cookiemonster Sorry I did't explain it clearly. I'll be careful next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the *error* is lost in limbo since the operating function did not "get a callback", viz., the error is "swallowed", since there is no callback to handle it.

```
var foo = function(onSuccess, onFailure) {
    // ... 
    // uh-oh, I failed
    if(onFailure) {
        onFailure(err);
    }
    else {
        // well, that probably wasn't too important anyway...
    }
}

foo(function() { console.log("success!"); } /* no second argument... */);
```

Note in synchronous coding (say, most Java) it's much harder for this to happen. Catch blocks are much better enforced and if an exception escapes anyway, it goes to the uncaught exception handler which by default crashes the system. It's like this in node too, *except* in the above paradigm where an exception isn't thrown it's likely swallowed.

Strong community convention could solve it in my trivial example above, but convention **can not** completely solve this in general. See e.g. the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) promise library which supports a `done` method.

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```

The `done` call there instructs the promise chain to throw any unhandled exceptions (if the catch block were missing, or the catch block itself throws). But it is fully the responsibility of the programmer to call `done`, as it must be, since only the programmer knows when the chain is complete. If a programmer forgets to call `done` the error will sit dangling in the promise chain. I have had real production bugs caused by this; I agree, it's a serious problem.

I'll be honest that a lot of that block in the post doesn't make much sense to me. But I'm an experienced Node.js programmer and this is the only thing I can think that could mean.

Comment: I see. Can I regard this problem as lack complete convention? Cause in this article, TJ said Go has a great convention in APIs design.

Comment: +1 I think this must be what was meant. I can't agree that Go is necessarily superior in this, since one can simply ignore a returned error. It's the same problem in a different spot. That said, I did ditch Node for Go and haven't looked back.

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang no, now that I think about it. see edit.

Comment: @djechlin So even we have a strong convention, the third package like [Q in promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) may have a different way to handle error. Forgot to pass error handler will make us lost in limbo.

Comment: @cookiemonster And I don't think the Go lack of package register's side effect is interesting. I regard it as a drawback.

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang no - you have to remember to handle the error and there's no compiler way to enforce it. It doesn't count as a convention if you can just forget it since it's easy to forget, then have a production bug. That's not a convention issue; it's a problem.

Comment: @djechlin: I've never used async libraries. Is there any pattern where it is reasonable to not call `.done()` immediately? If not, do you think that the internals should throw (or have an option to throw) if a `.done()` callback isn't provided?

Comment: @cookiemonster you return a promise. so the example above, but if it's happening in library code *not* responsible for throwing errors, you don't end in `.done();` you just return the whole chain (i.e. the resulting promise). actually the more common issue is dropping a `return` and client code interpreting it to mean "finished right away".

Comment: @cookiemonster rule is all promises should start with `return` or end in `done`. (Or have a comment explaining bug in library code prohibiting this).